# 16.04 Installer crashes on new Ultrabook

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, uefi, asus, ultrabook

I recently got a Asus Zenbook UX303B (or "303UB"). I installed Mint at first, but decided to migrate to Ubuntu after problems with the screen, the touchpad, and the touchscreen. On Ubuntu Live USB, these work well out-of-the-box.

However, I am unable to install. Twice I couldn't get past the first questions (3rd party software & update while installing), and four times it ran the partitioning (turns out I have UEFI, not BIOS, if that's an issue - I created a 50 MB EFI partition), but then:

The installer dies suddenly, while displaying *Almost finished copying files*. It just disappears. I've checked the drive integrity. I reboot, and get a GRUB console. When I reinstall, the installer sometimes recognizes Ubuntu 16.04 as existing, sometimes not.

How can I install Ubuntu successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Are you attempting to do a dual boot or do you want to install only Ubuntu?

Comment: Just Ubuntu. The PC came with functional Win 10 and Mint installed fine; I have no OS now, after (repeated) reformatting. I tried both partitioning myself and the default partitioning.